# IWebkit And HTML Table Not Rendering To Screen Size

Tags: php, html, mobile

I have been using the iwebkit framework and it is great. However, I am building a web app from work using exsiting PHP functions for customers to purchase products.

The only problem I'm running into is this. The existing code uses a for loop to spit out data from our DB into HTML tables. I could go through and change these to iwebkit list classes but the function is about 500 lines of code with hundreds of `<td>` and `<tr>` tags and as you can see replacing those would be a huge pain.

The issue is that the right part of the table it spits out gets cut off on a mobile device. Now the table is standard, no CSS formatting. I have tried re-sizing it using pixels and percentages but for some reason the table shrinks but doesn't fit to the viewport and is still cut off even though there is free space to the right.

Is there anyway to format a standard HTML table for a mobile device to fit to screen?

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful for integrating alternative CSS for mobile devices. From your description, it sounds a lot like there might be some interfering margins/paddings from surrounding elements or the table itself. I believe that tables are automatically rendered with some padding/margin combination, so that would be the first thing I would check.

http://perishablepress.com/the-5-minute-css-mobile-makeover/

Hope that fixs your problem!